# Pushbullet push with multiple options

Tags: android, pushbullet

I would like to control my home automation project with my Android phone but I don't know if it's possible the way I am thinking.

How exactly I would like to use it:

1. An Arduino Nano detects that one of the lights have been left on,
   but there is no movement in that room for x amount of time.
2. The Arduino Nano passes that information to my internet connected hub.
3. The hub (uses Processing code)  makes the Pushbullet API request to display a push that says
   "Light in room y has been left on for x amount of time, would you
   like to turn it off? YES/NO".

Would this be possible with Pushbullet? 
If yes, then how? 
If no, are there ways I could do this (as simply)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make arbitrary options on pushes but you could send a push to yourself to say "light in room ..." and then send a push in response, like "y" or "n".  The arduino could create the initial push and then read the response push.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You said "...(yet)..." does that mean I'll be able to do this in the future?

Comment: It's something that we've talked about adding, but for now we have no concrete plans.  I'll edit the response to remove the yet.